# Custom mongoose id : two ways of doing it, what are pros and cons?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Simple use case :

Let start with this simple model:

```
// Schema
var notebookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  }
});
```

Using this model, objects that comes in Mongo are in the form :

```
{ _id: 558ab637cab9a2b01dae9a97,
  title:"a notebook title"
}
```

I **DO NOT** want this kind of ids. I know there's some Express middlewares like [mongoose-short-id](https://github.com/jjwchoy/mongoose-shortid) or [mongoose-hook-custom-id](https://github.com/tarquas/mongoose-hook-custom-id/) than can do that, but I **DO NOT** want to use external dependencies.

So, I see two ways for doing this:

**1. Use a similar code than the libs I mentioned above, like this :**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema,
  Types = mongoose.Types,
  mongooseSave = mongoose.Model.prototype.save,
  SchemaString = mongoose.Schema.Types.String;

function CustomId (key) {
  SchemaString.call(this, key);
};

CustomId.prototype.__proto__ = SchemaString.prototype;
Schema.Types.CustomId = CustomId;
Types.CustomId = String;

mongoose.Model.prototype.save = function(callback) {
  for (field in this.schema.tree) {
    if (this.isNew && this[field] === undefined) {
      var fieldType = this.schema.tree[field];
      if (fieldType === CustomId || fieldType.type === CustomId) {
        var oid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
        var id = new Buffer('' + oid, 'hex').toString('base64').replace('+', '-').replace('/', '_');
        this[field] = id;
        mongooseSave.call(this, function(err, obj) {
          callback(err, obj);
        });
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  mongooseSave.call(this, callback);
};
module.exports = exports = CustomId;
```

usage:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var CustomId = require('../utils/custom_id');
// Schema
var BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {
    type: CustomId
  },
  title: {
    type: "string",
    required: true
  }
});
```

**2. Use a plugin approach, like this :**

```
// Schema
var notebookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {
    type: 'string'
  },
  title: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  }
});

var customIdPlugin = function(schema, options) {
  schema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var oid = ""+mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
    this._id = new Buffer(oid, 'hex').toString('base64').replace('+', '-').replace('/', '_');;
    next();
  });
};

notebookSchema.plugin(customIdPlugin );
```

These two approaches work fine, and I'm aware there's no "official magical standardized" ways, but can you tell me what would be your choice and why (pro and cons)

Comment: If I had to choose, I'd pick the plug-in version because it doesn't require monkeypatching. Why don't you want to use `ObjectId`'s, though?

Comment: I dont't want to use ObjectId's because of their length (24). In the example above I use a B64 ObjectId, reducing it's length to 16, but could be another generator like the one short-id uses (custom length, alphabet,...).

Comment: `ObjectId`'s take up [12 bytes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/).

Comment: Sure, but 24 characters in the hexadecimal string representation of the object...